# Jquery UI tabs - change the shape of tabs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Hi i was wandering if it's possible to change the shape of tabs,preferably using Jquery UI.

I would like to have something similar to the tabs below.

[image: tabs[1]]

Or could someone advise my any method to achive this using css?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It certainly is possible to override the default styling, but we will need to see your current code to be able to help you do so.

Comment: I found similar topic where user provided this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/96sv3/2/ but i was unable to match it to the one i want

Comment: Closes i got was https://jsfiddle.net/Reszkov/smdxk01n/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used some jquery for the tab-switching but the tab-styling is entirely done with css, is this what you were looking for?

snippet below or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zge9hkb6/)

```js
$('#tabwrapper ul li').on('click', function () {
 var divToShow = $(this).data('target');
  var root = $(this).closest('div');
  $('> div > div', root).hide();
  $('> div > div#' + divToShow, root).show();
});
```

```css
html, body, div, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}  
li {  
  float: left;  
  padding: 4px 15px 4px 30px;
 position: relative;
 background: #88b7d5;
 border: 1px solid #c2e1f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li + li {
  margin-left: 0;
}
li:after, li:before {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
li:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-left-color: #88b7d5;
 border-width: 13px;
 margin-top: 0px;  
}
li:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-left-color: #c2e1f5;
 border-width: 14px;
 margin-top: -1px;
  z-index: 1;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #c2e1f5;
}
li:hover:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-left-color: #444;
  }
#tabwrapper {  
  border: 1px solid #88b7d5;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 12px;  
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#tabwrapper > div {
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
#tabwrapper > div > div {
  display: none;
  mine-height: 50px
}
#tabwrapper > div > div:first-child {
  display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabwrapper">
<ul>
  <li data-target="tabcontent1">test1</li>
  <li data-target="tabcontent2">test2</li>
  <li data-target="tabcontent3">test3</li>
  <li data-target="tabcontent4">test4</li>
</ul>
<div style="clear: both;">
  <div id="tabcontent1">content1</div>
  <div id="tabcontent2">content2</div>
  <div id="tabcontent3">content3</div>
  <div id="tabcontent4">content4</div>
</div>
</div>
```